# Empty ResultSet w/ working connection and correct SQL statement

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to debug why my db connection can't seem to fetch any rows from my database. I'm able to connect to the db (postgres) without issue and don't get any exceptions when executing queries, but for some reason they always return an empty ResultSet.

```
byte[] decodedstrDbPassword = Base64.getDecoder().decode(strDbPassword);
String dbpwd = new String(decodedstrDbPassword, "utf-8");
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
static Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(strDbUrl, strDbUser, dbpwd);
ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM my_table;");
if (rs.next()) {
   System.out.println("Got a row");
}
```

I've taken the `originalQuery` from the ResultSet object and independently executed it against my database and it returns a bunch of rows, and at a glance the `fields` field from ResultSet has obtained all the correct column types from `my_table`. It just seems to not get any rows when I try to fetch them with `rs.next()`.

Anything I might be missing here that might give me trouble when it comes to fetching rows? Thanks in advance for any tips/advice.

Comment: Are the rows committed in the transaction that inserts them? Could there be two `my_table` in different schemas?

Comment: Rows are committed in separate transactions from the insertions, but I'm certain they're there. I have `my_table` in both a QA and DEV schema but both databases have rows that the above query should select.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Semikolon at the end. Might be ignored to avoid SQL injection. Try it without the ; at the end